# stopping a service using stopself()

Tags: android, android-service

I have written a service which listens to some callbacks and gets the VCards and then passes it to the VCardService (This class was defined in the android contacts app and I am making use of the same). Now I want to stop this service when the VCardService stops. I know that we can check if a service is still running or not.But what I want is the calling Service should know only when the service is finished . Not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quit sure what exactly you want, but if you want to stop service by its own when the task is done, here is the solution:

suppos you have a class which extends service

```
public  class MyPersonalService extends Service {
            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                // suppose you are downloading some file, so when you finished downloading your file, just call self stop like this:

                this.stopSelf();
            }
```

Calling stopSelf() method will stop the service, you dont have to stop it by your self, you just have to know from where and when to call stopSelf() method.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Got the solution. I am implementing listener myself which will notify when the called service finishes.

Comment: How are you doing this? I need my application to know when my service is finished...

Comment: I'm not using onCreate() in my MyService class, but rather just the onStartCommand(). Can I put it in there in the end? I just tried, it does not work. Says, "unreachable code".

Comment: as onCreate() is called automatically before onStartCommand() method if the service is not already runnign. You can use it and put your code there. Or u can call stopSelf(), remember if you want to provide binding you dont have to use above.